# Android Studio not showing Chrome as Flutter device

Tags: android-studio, google-chrome, flutter

I got a small problem which accured after reinstalling Android Studio:
[Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UakeV.png)

Android Studio is not showing Chrome as Device for my Flutter Web project, while flutter doctor shows clearly everything is enabled correctly:
[Flutter doctor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X41YM.png)

I can normally run the flutter project on google chrome using the console or VS Code, but Android Studio does not work. I already checked the Flutter and Dart plugin.

I would be glad if someone who maybe had the same issue or knows how to fix this gets back to me!

Best Regards

Comment: what channel are you on? type flutter channel in terminal

Answer (score 9):

1. Clearly it is not the issue with flutter. It is an issue with your Android Studio installation. You can verify the same by navigating to the your project folder in the terminal (or command prompt) and type

`flutter run -d Chrome`.

NOTE: The above command works only if you are on `master`, `beta` or `dev` branch and you have already enabled your flutter web support by typing

`flutter config --enable-web`

2. I noticed that your path to Android Studio as: C:\Program Files\Android\ **Android Studio1**

It means that during installation the original **Android Studio** folder is not deleted. A duplicate folder has been created in the same location. Hence the Android `sdk` location is must be changed as well.

You can solve this by:

1. Uninstall Android Studio. Delete the folder at the above location. Reinstall Android Studio. Update `sdk` path in your `sdk manager` as well as in your environment variable. (**recommended**).
2. Update the `sdk` folder in the `sdk manager` as well as your environment variables.

Comment: `flutter config --enable-web` was the key. Thanks